# Debugging Windows 8 app different versions

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have an app that is in the windows 8 store. Now I am releasing the next version of the app. Since I have made changes in the code I need to debug it with the previous version installed. If I install the app via power shell the app is updating. If I install new version app with existing previous version app the visual studio 2012 is deleting the previous version and reinstalls it. So how to debug new version without deleting the previous version data in VS 2012 Express for windows 8?

Comment: Why don't you change the Package Name in manifest file so that both apps exists in you system.

Comment: That is just like installing a new app.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the existing data, install the new version and copy back the relevant data?

Answer (score 0):

If you increment the version number on your application's packages, the old data will not be erased. You can manually set the version number when you create your application package, or have Visual Studio automatically increment the version number (click the checkbox option):

[image: Set Package Version Number]

Also, you should make sure that the build option to clean out application data is unchecked (last option in image):

[image: Build option to clean app data]

Comment: I am doing the same thing, if I create app package its working fine, then if I launch app from VS 2012 the data is getting deleted.

Comment: @nucleons - Sorry to hear that. The only time my data gets erased is if I try to install a version of my software that has an older (or same) version number. How/where do you store the app data?

Comment: Storing in app Local folder.

Comment: I also referred http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-FI/winappswithcsharp/thread/ca9c927e-60b7-4340-808b-3e7eca887be8